# Can someone clarify this linear transformation question for me please?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, and $T: V \rightarrow V$ a linear transformation such that $T(5\vec{v} + 3\vec{u})$ = $4\vec{v} + 5\vec{u} $ and $T(3\vec{v} + 2\vec{u})$ = $-3\vec{v} -5 \vec{u} .$

Then:

$T(\vec{v})$ = ___ $\vec{v}$ + ____ $\vec{u}$

$T(\vec{u})$ = ___ $\vec{v}$ + ____ $\vec{u}$

$T(-4\vec{v} + 4\vec{u})$  = ___ $\vec{v}$ + ____ $\vec{u}$

I'm having trouble figuring out how to approach this question. If anyone could explain this step by step that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linearity of $T$ means that, for scalars $a,b$ and $u,v\in V$ we have $T(au+bv)=aT(u)+bT(v)$. Thus,
$$T(3v+2u)=-3v-5u\implies 3T(v)+2T(u)=-3v-5u\qquad (1)\\T(5v+3u)=4v+5u\implies 5T(v)+3T(u)=4v+5u\qquad (2)$$
Using equation $(2)$ we have $T(v)=\frac{1}{5}\left(4v+5u-3T(u)\right)$. Substituting back into equation $(1)$ we have $3\left(\frac{1}{5}\left(4v+5u-3T(u)\right)\right)+2T(u)=-3v-5u$.

Rearrange and solve for $T(u)$, then plug that back into the rearranged equation $(2)$ to find $T(v)$ (both in terms of $u$ and $v$).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$
v = 2(5v + 3u) - 3(3v + 2u)\\
u = -\frac 13 [3(5v + 3u) - 5(3v + 2u)]
$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Put $$\vec {a}=5\vec {v}+3\vec {u} $$
and
$$\vec {b}=3\vec {v}+2\vec {u} $$

express $\vec {u} $ and $\vec {v} $.